# Thread executes "slowly"

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am starting with threads and wrote for the sake of learning the following simple program, which later would be used to calculate about 100,000 times a formula (it is a relatively simple one but which takes an iterated range of values).

The problem with it is that I expected every thread to execute in almost no time and thus the complete program to finish nearly immediately, but the fact is that everything runs too slow (about 10s)...

```
    static readonly double TotalIterations = 1000;

    public static Iterations ActualIterations = new Iterations();

    public static void Main()
    {

        var par1 = "foo";
        var par2 = "boo";
        var par3 = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalIterations; i++)
        {
            new Thread(() => new Calculations().Calculate(par1, par2, par3)).Start();
        }

        AwaitingThreads();
    }

    static void AwaitThreads()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Awaiting threads to finished...");

        while (true)
        {
            lock (ActualIterations)
            {
                if (ActualIterations.Progress() == TotalIterations) break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All threads finished!");
    }

    public class Calculations {

        public bool Calculate(string par1, string par2, int par3)
        {
            // ...

            bool result = false;

            lock (ActualIterations)
            {
                ActualIterations.Incr();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Iterations
    {
        int progress = 0;

        public void Incr()
        {
            progress++;
        }

        public int Progress()
        {
            return progress;
        }
    }
```

I also tried using a ThreadPool like this, but there was no improvement...

```
    static readonly double TotalIterations = 1000;

    static string par1 = "foo";
    static string par2 = "boo";
    static int par3 = 3;

    public static Iterations ActualIterations = new Iterations();

    public static void Main()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyThreadPool);

        AwaitThreads();
    }

    static void AwaitThreads()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Awaiting threads to finished...");

        while (true)
        {
            lock (ActualIterations)
            {
                if (ActualIterations.Progress() == TotalIterations) break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All threads finished!");
    }

    static void MyThreadPool(Object stateInfo)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalIterations; i++)
        {
            new Thread(() => new Calculations().Calculate(par1, par2, par3)).Start();
        }
    }

    public class Calculations {

        public bool Calculate(string par1, string par2, int par3)
        {
            // ...

            bool result = false;

            lock (ActualIterations)
            {
                ActualIterations.Incr();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Iterations
    {
        int progress = 0;

        public void Incr()
        {
            progress++;
        }

        public int Progress()
        {
            return progress;
        }
    }
```

When I quit using threads in this example and use a static method, executing it sequentially in my `for` loop, the program finishes in 1s...

Can anybody enlighten me what I am doing wrong here with those threads?

Comment: I don't think you're using the thread pool correctly in the second example. You're effectively launching a thread to launch all of your threads, rather than launching all of your threads through the thread pool.

Comment: Thread creation and thread switching is extremely expensive. So you using 1000 threads concurrently where the system needs to constantly switch between them, would slow everything down. Whereas in your second example you only have one worker thread (which is even a (probably) reused one) from the ThreadPool, so you don't have a lot of thread switching and the program can actually get its work done. That aside you shouldn't really start with threads, but rather use Tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to proceed doing what you wanted to do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calculations " + DateTime.Now);         
            }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Tasks are actually optimized and programmer-friendly to use if you need to work with threads.

Another advice i want to give you is to create an `Object` just for locking purposes, example:

```
class Program
{
    private static Object _locker = new Object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Calculations " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the working example on how to use `Task<T>` in my context.
I tested it already with my real formula (100,000 calculations) and:
a) without threads and tasks it took 9s
b) with threads... i gave up after 5min...
c) with task... took 3s !
Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

> The problem with it is that I expected every thread to execute in almost no time

Right. You're ignoring the fact that creating a new thread is a relatively expensive operation. Far, far more expensive than "acquiring a lock and incrementing an integer" which is the work you're doing *in* the thread.

To give a real world comparison, it's a little like ordering a new car, waiting it to be delivered, and then driving it 1km. That's going to be slower than just walking 1km.

Using the thread pool would be faster, but you're not using it correctly - you're launching *one* thread pool task which then creates all the other threads again.

I would encourage you to look at using `Task<T>` instead, which normally uses the thread pool under the hood, and is a generally more modern abstraction for this sort of work.

Comment: Thanks for your car-example, it was great!
May I ask you for a `Taskl<T>` usage in my context?

Comment: @anna: Well we don't know what your *real* use case is, so it's hard to say. A lot of the time you'd use asynchronous methods anyway these days - but the best solution will depend on context, and I'm assuming your real use case isn't just "incrementing an integer in parallel". You might want to start by reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency

Comment: @JonSkeet Little question, isn't locking on the object (here `ActualIterations`) you want to use not a good practice ? Isn't it better to lock on an `Object` lock that you created just for that ?

Comment: @PhilippeB.: There's a lot I'd change about this code - for the purpose of just incrementing an integer, I'd use `Interlocked`, for example. But yes, I personally *usually* create an object just for locking.

Answer (score -1):

I see the problem in the `AwaitThreads` method.
It uses the same `lock (ActualIterations)` as working thread and it makes working threads to wait for shared resource additionally.

Also (as it was mentioned by @Euphoric) the thread working code you have shown is just about single increment and it uses the shared resource between all threads.

You have to change it in some another way and try to avoid shared resource usage in multi threaded environment.

For example, if you need to make some calculation on huge data array you have to feed each thread own data part to be processed and then wait for all tasks to be finished. There is `Task` concept and [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I've tested this - while locking like this is far from ideal, it's not the bottleneck here. Creating a single thread for each operation is.

Comment: @JonSkeet well, creating 1000 threads|tasks does not make sense. So many Tasks will wait for ThreadPool queue. And Threads creation is really heavy you are absolutely right. But look - 1000 threads|tasks is too much. I do not think that there is real need to have so many methods running in "parallel" Any sync operation between thread is a place were production code will stuck so it should be avoid (if possible). I'd like to check the real code (not the artificial sample) and how those threads|tasks are supplied with data.

Comment: I agree that it would be at least unusual for 1000 threads to make sense. But my point is that your answer points to this as being the cause of the slow-down - and it's not the primary cause. While it's not a good idea anyway, it's the thread creation that is the bottleneck in the code that we've got here.